# Connecting logout with image in php

Tags: php, html

with this command, I get a link to the logout command, how can I match a picture to this ?. Thank you

```
<?php echo $login->get_link_logout(); ?>
```

Comment: If you can add more information it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for this

```
<a href="<?php echo $login->get_link_logout(); ?>"><IMG src="YOUR IMAGE URL"></a>
```

**YOUR IMAGE URL** is the url of the image which you want to use as a logout link/icon.

Comment: I thank you, I felt that way, but remains with the inscription Logout hypertext and image without connection